# HTML:Cannot display my image

Tags: html

Note:All my files are in the same directory.

I wrote a simple HTML to display the image.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <p style="font-size:xx-large; font-weight:900;">My homework test</p>

        <!--Load a image-->
        <img src="mini.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i open this html directly, it can display the image correctly.

But when I try to use my node.js server to open the html, it cannot show the image.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-I - press it and look for errors in the console. It should give you a hint. I imagine there's bound to be something funny going on with the path of the image requested. (though have no node.js experience)

Comment: seems like image path is wrong, try `./mini.jpg`?

Comment: Is this HTML file in the same directory/folder as your image? If not, you will need to provide the full path in `src`.

Comment: @MrNew that won't make a difference.

Comment: The you'll need to provide the full path, like what @Tricky12 said.

Comment: The image is not in the same folder as the html file or you misspelled the name of the image

Comment: @Tricky12   Sorry, But all the files are in the same folder. :(

Comment: @enhzflep  After I press Ctrl-Shift-I, the error message appears: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)."

Comment: I have found the problem.
The problem lies in my node.js code.
Thank you for all those who suggested me.